# Replace if starts with something and ends with something

Tags: java, regex, replace

Consider the following:

```
String test = "%placeholder_test% %placeholder_another%";
```

What should be the regex to be put in `test.replaceAll(regex, "placeholder")` so that the string section will be replaced with "placeholder" if starting with "%placeholder_" and ending with "%"?

Expected output: "placeholder placeholder".

Comment: You are getting down vote because you haven't shown your own code attempt with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple regex :

```
/%placeholder_[^%]+%/
```

**Explanation :**

1. `%placeholder_` matches the first part literally.
2. `[^%]` matches any character that is not '%' (anything not placed in [^...] will be matched).
3. The `+` matches any sequence of characters at least one or more times.
4. `%` matches the '%' character literally.

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6AH6Mm/3/)

You should start learning regular expressions by yourself, try looking at this [cheat sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) for a starter.

Comment: What is the usage of +?

Comment: I added some explanations to help you understand. The link I have you at the end of my answer will guide you well through the steps.

Comment: Why do you escape `%`? It is not a special character in regex.

Comment: You're right, it's my bad, Regex101.com just assumed % was my delimiter when I started typing my regex, I didn't pay attention and then assumed I had to escape it x) I edited my post to correct that.